# Regular Expression to find and replace preserving case

Tags: regex, flashdevelop

I want to use a RegExp in a find and replace dialog. Such that :

```
abcd ==> replaced by ==> efgh 

Abcd ==> replaced by ==> Efgh

ABCD ==> replaced by ==> EFGH

aBcD ==> replaced by ==> eFgH
```

etc.

I know that RegExp can help me find a particular match. But I doubt that what I am looking for can be done by RegExp. As the match changes for different instances of the word.

Comment: You can simply increment.. As these characters are ordered in the ASCII table.

Comment: Regex is not meant for that..It's only used for pattern matching..Though you can do that in certain regex flavours.Please specify the language/tool you are using

Comment: Using Flash Develop ( Find and Replace dialog)

Comment: While not being familiar with Flash Develop, most Find and Replace dialogs don't have much options in the way of preserving case. If there's no box to tick in the dialog, you're out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

You'd better find another tool/function.

For example, in ruby, you can use `String#tr`:

```
from, to = 'abcd', 'efgh'
mapping = from + from.upcase, to + to.upcase # mapping = 'abcdABCD', 'efghEFGH'
'abcd'.tr(*mapping) # => "efgh"
'Abcd'.tr(*mapping) # => "Efgh"
'ABCD'.tr(*mapping) # => "EFGH"
'aBcD'.tr(*mapping) # => "eFgH"
```

In shell:

```
$ echo aBcD | tr abcdABCD efghEFGH
eFgH
```

If you really want to use regular expression, you maybe need to pass some kind of callback function.

Using the idea of Maroun Maroun in the comment.

```
'aBcD'.gsub(/[abcd]/i) { |x| (x.ord + 4).chr }
# => "eFgH"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with Regular Expressions.

You need to increment the ASCII values.

### Cmdlet

```
# Powershell v 3.0

Param(
    [string]$string,
    [int]$increment
)

$string.GetEnumerator() | % {
    $new_string += [char]([int]$_+$increment)
}

return $new_string
```

### Using Cmdlet

```
PS C:\> @("abcd","Abcd","ABCD","aBcD") | % {
>>     .\incChars.ps1 -string $_ -increment 4
>> }
efgh
Efgh
EFGH
eFgH
```